# how to create custom http header using secretkey?

Tags: php, header, response, phalcon

I want to create a custom header with secretkey as key, anyone can show me how to do this? I use the phalcon php framework.

```
public function onConstruct()
{
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    ?
}
```

I want to get api like this image on postman.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use:

```php
header('HeaderName: HeaderValue');
```

or with phalcon in your controller:

```php
$this->response->setHeader('HeaderName', 'HeaderValue');
```